# Squid Connection Refused HTTPS

Tags: proxy, squid

I have managed to get my HTTP "proxy" connection to work but on most https connections I get the error:

> Connection to  failed.
>
> The system returned: (111) Connection refused

Here is my config file I am currently using in squid:

```
http_port 3128

refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320

acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC 1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC 1918 possible internal network
acl myhost src <myip>
http_access allow myhost
acl SSL_ports port 443

acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT


via off
forwarded_for off

http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow all
dns_nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Running on a Ubuntu 12.04 VPS - connecting remotely via the browser proxy settings page...

All I want to do is to be able to connect to my server and browse http and https sites. Http works with the config above... https does not...

Answer (score 2):

Remove the following line:

```
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
```

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend keeping

```
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
```

but allowing those listed by adding:

```
http_access allow SSL_ports
```